# Encoding characters in restful resource path with ActiveResource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, activeresource

I've created a Rest API for a existing system utilizing Rails and am attempting to consume it in an external system via ActiveResource.  Unfortunately the primary key of one of the core tables is an arbitrary string defined by the user so many non-URL friendly characters have been used over the years. We've ended up with keys such as "CR 1400/2400 A-C", which ActiveResource is not encoding correctly into a restful URL.  It is deals with the spaces correctly, but does not encode the forward slashes amongst other characters.

I would like to be able to call the find method with the primary key containing these forbidden characters such as:

```
p = Project.find('CR 1400/2400 A-C')
```

which would result in a url such as:

http://localhost:3000/projects/CR%201400%2F2400%20A-C.json

instead of:

http://localhost:3000/projects/CR%201400/2400%20A-C.json

I cannot change the database schema even though currently very little would bring me greater joy.

Is there a way to tell ActiveResource to encode additional characters, or intercept the call to encode them prior to constructing the URL?

Thanks in advance

Neil